# Return DecodeJpeg from Image in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm retriving contacts from WP7. Some contacts having images some not having. I want to show default image those contacts not having image.

I have used the following image converter,

```
public class ContactPictureConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Contact c = value as Contact;
            if (c == null) return null;

            System.IO.Stream imageStream = c.GetPicture();


            if (null != imageStream)
            {
                return Microsoft.Phone.PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

In that if imageStream is null then i want to return my default image.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shared variable in the `App` class of your project where you can refer to in your converter.

Or better and recommended, you just use an `BitmapSource` with relative URL to your ressource image.

[BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage
                            {
                                UriSource = 
                                    new Uri("../Images/Test.JPG", UriKind.Relative)
                            };
```

or VB

```
Dim bitmapImage = New BitmapImage() With { _
    Key .UriSource = New Uri("../Images/Test.JPG", UriKind.Relative)}
```